# A small miscalculation in my coordinat system

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to store coordinate points in a double variable. It is very simple. I have x and y coordinates. My double variable stores them like that x.y . When I tried to convert this value into separate coordinates, I had some troubles.

I have tried these codes but still get same error.

```
 //First try
 double temp=memory.pop();
 int x=(int)temp;
 int y=(int)((temp-(int)temp)*100);
 //Second try
 double temp=memory.pop();
 int x=(int)temp;
 int y=100.0f*temp-(((int)temp)*100.0f);
```

In temp variable, I have 5.14 double number. After calculations, x should be 5 and y should be 14. However, x become 5, y become 13.

Comment: Sorry but that is a terrible idea. Floating point numbers don't have infinite precision at all. Use two variables.

Comment: You "could" store two `int32_t` as `uint32_t` in a single `uint64_t` and access them using bit shifting and bit masking, but why don't you simply use a `class` with two `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to integer casting. Specfically `(int)temp` will floor to the first smaller integer. For insance, the value *5,14* can be (and probably is) not exaclty that but a bit smaller/larger for a matter of precision (since, as said in comments, the floating point numbers don't have infinite precision). So without loss of generality let's say that is *5,13999999999999*, you can see that when you perform your operation you will obtain *13* instead of *14* for the second part of the coordinate.

Comment: @Red.Wave Why are you asking me? :) I didn't mark it as a dupe

Comment: The mark is done after last post. Where else do you suggest?

Comment: Short answer: x= std::floor(temp); y= std::round((temp-x)*100);

Comment: @Red.Wave You should comment on the question, not on my answer :)